# ASP.Net Web API controller Get request not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a OrderDetails table. I'm trying to get all its contents but its not working. If someone can point out why it's not getting any data that would be very helpful. And yes I have data in OrderDetails table and connection is alright.

OrderDetail.cs

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int odid { get; set; }
    public int oid { get; set; }
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Aproduct { get; set; }

}
```

OrderDetailsController.cs

```
    private static readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orders = new OrderDetailRepository();
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> Get()
    {
        return _orders.GetAll();
    }
```

OrderDetailRepository.cs

```
    private readonly MediaSoftContext _db;

    public OrderDetailRepository()
    {
        _db = new MediaSoftContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.OrderDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Check that the correct route is defined

Comment: yes, the route is ok. Checked multiple times already.

Comment: Could you please post your connectionstring and webapiconfig.cs files? And do you get any errors when you navigate to /OrderDetails url? Or do you have any other controller that works?